# Unable to link to child state in Angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I link to a nested child state, it redirects to the parent state. I've tried:

`<a ui-sref="hub.create-product">Create</a>`

and

`<a href="#/hub/create-product">Create</a>`

but both links go to `#/hub` instead of `#hub/create-product` when clicked.

Any suggestion on what may be causing this?

```js
angular.module('pmApp.hub', [])
    .config([
        '$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
              .state('hub', {
                  url: '/hub',
                  menuName: 'hub',
                  controller: 'hubCtrl',
                  reloadOnSearch: false
              })
               .state('hub.intro', {
                   url: '/intro',
                   menuName: 'hub',
                   reloadOnSearch: false
               })
              .state('hub.create-product', {
                  url: '/create-product',
                  menuName: 'hub',
                  reloadOnSearch: false
              });
            }
    ]);
```

Comment: compare to: https://plnkr.co/edit/nnK1Vc?p=info

Comment: Your code looks clean and there is no issue found. Can you confirm that you are running the code in localhost